# What do contemporay philosophers say about Hegel's aesthetics beyond interpretation?

Tags: aesthetics, hegel

> Hegel's philosophy of art is a wide ranging account of beauty in art,
>   the historical development of art, and the individual arts of
>   architecture, sculpture, painting, music and poetry. It contains
>   distinctive and influential analyses of Egyptian art, Greek sculpture,
>   and ancient and modern tragedy, and is regarded by many as one of the
>   greatest aesthetic theories to have been produced since Aristotle's
>   Poetics.

[This article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hegel-aesthetics/) makes a lot of claims about art but has no commentary on contemporary involvement with Hegel's aesthetics, beyond that it is often critical. Can anyone sketch what contemporary philosophers use Hegel's aesthetics, beyond interpreting what was said?

Comment: See Robert Pippin, After the Beautiful: Hegel and the Philosophy of Pictorial Modernism, also https://uchicago.app.box.com/s/hwmbnz8n64h25beqmwqgfk2qy0gn657f , but unfortunately I don't know enough for an answer.